# Partitioning Guide for Linux. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I am new to Linux world and I would like to help me make the best partitioning choice. I am gonna use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as my main OS on my desktop PC. Basically I use my PC for : coding, surfing Internet, watching movies, listening to music, maybe sometimes playing games.

So help me choose:

- What directories will need partitions ?
- What file system should I use ?
- What type of partitions should it be ? Logical or Primary ?
- Should it be on the Beginning or the End of the drive ?

Comment: This install guide covers basic partitioning http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu and this one, if you want something more advanced http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation